# How to delete comments on a feed with Facebook graph api?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to delete a comment with comment id of post in the group of me.

What I've done now:

- Step 1: Get post with comment
  I use explorer tool to request using get method:
  me/groups/admin_only=true?fields=feed{comments}
- Step 2: Delete comment using received comment id
  I use explorer tool with delete method and comment id to delete a comment:
  me/[comment-id]

But I got an error response
[image]

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3,
    "fbtrace_id": "AeBG_fBv3rCZGW4vqYQPpj3"
  }
}
```

I have set `pages_manage_engagement` permission to my access token.

How to fix this error and delete the comment?

Comment: _"I have set 'pages_manage_engagement' permission to my access token."_ - that doesn't make your user access token into a page access token though; the latter is something you have to get first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can I delete comment on a feed in a group (not page) that I manage with graph api? I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: Not sure, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/#deleting only talks about it in regard to a page feed.